windows listview virtual mode, Is there a bug when pressing shift to select multiple items?
windows listview  virtual mode,  Is there a bug when pressing shift to select multiple items  ?
c#  my code:
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView2.VirtualMode = true;
        listView2.VirtualListSize = 100;
    }

    private void listView2_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item == null)
            e.Item = new ListViewItem(e.ItemIndex.ToString()); 

    }


I tried it in Delphi and it was the same.
There is no such problem when not using virtual mode.
I expect that the red-framed options in git should not be selected
It is icon mode. No icon is added to imagelist.
Is it that I don't know how to use it, or is there a bug in Windows?

C# or Delphi (VCL)? And what happens (and what did you expect)?

I expect that the red-framed options in git should not be selected  https://i.sstatic.net/Qs5gDaRn.gif

FWIW: I have been working with virtual list view controls in Delphi (VCL TListView, Win32 List View) daily for years and have never observed any bug related to this. But I almost only work with list views in the "report" ("details") view style. In fact, I have hardly ever seen a virtual list view control that is not in that style.

It is icon mode. No icon is added to imagelist.
